# Getting data through entity model Relational tables in ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I am creating a web api to get all transactions with object of country, currency which is foreign key here.

I have a controller with method

```
   [Route("transactions")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetCountries()
        {
            return Ok(db.PAY_TRANSACTION);
        }
```

This is my Entity Model

```
 public partial class PAY_TRANSACTION
    {
        public PAY_TRANSACTION()
        {
            this.PAY_BATCH_TRANSACTION = new HashSet<PAY_BATCH_TRANSACTION>();
            this.PAY_TRANSACTION_DETAIL = new HashSet<PAY_TRANSACTION_DETAIL>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int CMN_INSTITUTE_ID { get; set; }
        public int USER_ID { get; set; }
        public int MAS_COUNTRY_ID { get; set; }
        public int CMN_CURRENCY_ID { get; set; }
        public double AMOUNT_PAYING { get; set; }
        public double EXCHANGE_RATE { get; set; }
        public double AMOUNT_FX { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CREATED_ON { get; set; }
        public int CREATED_BY { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime UPDATED_ON { get; set; }
        public int UPDATED_BY { get; set; }
        public bool IS_DELETED { get; set; }
        public bool IS_APPROVED { get; set; }
        public int VERSION_NO { get; set; }

        public virtual CMN_CURRENCY CMN_CURRENCY { get; set; }
        public virtual CMN_INSTITUTE CMN_INSTITUTE { get; set; }
        public virtual MAS_COUNTRY MAS_COUNTRY { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PAY_BATCH_TRANSACTION> PAY_BATCH_TRANSACTION { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PAY_TRANSACTION_DETAIL> PAY_TRANSACTION_DETAIL { get; set; }
    }
```

When I request for methods I get this error:

> Invalid column name 'MAS_COUNTRY_ID1'.\r\nInvalid column name 'CMN_INSTITUTE_ID1'.\r\nInvalid column name 'CMN_CURRENCY_ID1'.

When I set [ForeignKey("CMN_INSTITUTE_ID ")], [ForeignKey("MAS_COUNTRY_ID ")],
[ForeignKey("CMN_CURRENCY_ID ")], I get this response

```
{
  "ID": 7,
  "CMN_INSTITUTE_ID": 2,
  "USER_ID": 3,
  "MAS_COUNTRY_ID": 1,
  "CMN_CURRENCY_ID": 2,
  "AMOUNT_PAYING": 123,
  "EXCHANGE_RATE": 1.2,
  "AMOUNT_FX": 22,
  "CREATED_ON": "2017-01-18T17:50:16.993",
  "CREATED_BY": 0,
  "UPDATED_ON": "2017-01-18T17:50:16.993",
  "UPDATED_BY": 0,
  "IS_DELETED": false,
  "IS_APPROVED": false,
  "VERSION_NO": 0,
  "CMN_CURRENCY": null,
  "CMN_INSTITUTE": null,
  "MAS_COUNTRY": null,
  "PAY_BATCH_TRANSACTION": [],
  "PAY_TRANSACTION_DETAIL": []
}
```

which is showing my MAS_COUNTRY, CMN_INSTITUTE, CMN_CURRENCY **NULL**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those related entities will not get loaded until its accessed( `Lazy Loading`). In your case you are not accessing those entities before sending it back  and hence those properties will never get loaded. 
You can `Eager Load` those entities in your case, `db.PAY_TRANSACTION.Include (t=> t.MAS_COUNTRY).Include (t=>t.CMN_INSTITUTE).Include (t=>t.CMN_CURRENCY)`

Comment: I am getting error
Self referencing loop detected with type 'AspNetIdentity.Models.PAY_TRANSACTION'. Path 'CMN_CURRENCY.PAY_TRANSACTION'.",

Comment: Either set `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Re‌​ferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;` or assign the output to custom object before sending back.

Comment: Thanks alot pal. You are PRO!